# Is there any difference in meaning?

Tags: grammar

**1- Otters and Beavers have two layers of fur.**

### 2- Both Otters and Beavers have two layers of fur.

It seems to me in sentence 1 each animal has its own two layers of fur whereas in sentence 2 , I think the meaning can be both animals shared the two layers.

Am I right or wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the meanings are identical. In this context, because it would be absurd to suggest they share the fur.

If you wanted to suggest that they share the layers, you would have to say so explicitly.

Whether you need to be explicit is dependent on context though.

Comment: Thank you @PRL75  1.  I know it is absurd, but the grammar itself can make ambiguity or rather difference.  2.  I think so, because English language has always faults with. Not a precise language.   If it is another verb used not ( have )  Yes it can be identical as you said. The verb have =  possessive  ( You have a car )  Suppose it  You and I have a car.  Both you and I have a car ?    The sentence with ( both ) + have  it can be misleading ?

Comment: If you're worried about ambiguity you can use words like "each" and "own", e.g. "Both Otters and Beavers each have their own two layers of fur." But this is not normally necessary. If you have another case where you think it's ambiguous, ask about that, not beavers.

Comment: It's an "elephant in my pajamas" situation. If you can't imagine how the elephant got into your pajamas...